# Difference in routing between ASP.NET 4.6 and Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm converting my ASP.NET 4.6 server software to Core.

In my old project I had:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "DefaultApi",
   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then a controller with two functions:

```
[Route("api/v2/users")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get()

[Route("api/v2/users")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetByEmail([FromUri]string Email)
```

This worked.

Now in the new project I have the same controller, but with no initial default routing template, since I didn't want to use it anyway.

```
[Route("api/v2/[controller]")]
public class UsersController : Controller
```

With the same two functions

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByEmail([FromQuery]string email)
```

But now I get the AmbiguousActionException. I know I could essentially optimize this into one function and also make it more REST-by-the-book, but the question is: what changed? Has ASP.NET Core become more strict? Or am I simply missing something?

EDIT: Both implementations use the same route for both functions - "api/v2/users" - but in the first there's no AmbiguousActionException. So it means that in that case the router can distinguish by the query parameter, while in the second it cannot. To the best of my knowledge this is not related to the default route template since I was overruling it anyway.

Comment: You can still do that kind of routing in [ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Create a Web API with ASP.NET Core and Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: @John That means: This question has an answer here.

Comment: @Tan Perhaps you could add that as an answer, including the core information as text in your answer?

Comment: @Foo I don't see how the question has an answer there. The tutorial only shows routing based on route path and not on query parameters. The problem still persists. I can do something in .NET Framework which I cannot do in .NET Core. Since I'm migrating from the former to the latter, it's kind of frustrating that I cannot find the solution.